# select DOM with Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('#example')[0].onmouseover = function(event) {
     alert("something");
    };
  });
</script>
```

```
<body>
<img id="example" src="example.jpg" " alt="ooooh! ahhhh!"/>
</body
```

Why do we need [0] behind example id ?

why it's not working if we remove [0] ?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are calling native `onmouseover` you need to refer native DOM Element

```
$('#example')[0] // gives native DOM Element.

$('#example')[0].onmouseover=function(){}; //native event handling
```

If you remove `[0]` then you are referring jQuery object. So you need to use jQuery way of event handling

```
$('#example') //gives jQuery object
$('#example').mouseover(function(){}); //jQuery event handling
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).on("mouseover","#example",function(event) {
 alert("something");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`.onmouseover` is a JavaScript event handler and only applies to DOM elements.  Since `$('#example')` is a jQuery object, `onmouseover` wouldn't do anything at all (not even produce an error).

However, each jQuery object also masquerades as an array, so we can use the array dereferencing operator to get at the underlying element via `$('#example')[0]` which returns an element that `onmouseover` (and any other native JavaScript event handler) can work with.